# Semantics of "Implies" on command line switches

Tags: windows-7, command-line, chkdsk, command-line-arguments, disk-cleanup

**Silly question:**   I *thought* I knew what an *implication* was, until looking into this.  I'd like to confirm the definition of `implied` in the context of Windows command prompt switches.  For example:

- If the description for switch `/R` says **`(implies /F)`**, **does that mean that using this switch *automatically also includes* `/F`** regardless of whether I add it?
- **Or** is it just ***strongly suggested*** that I add `/F`?

<sub>*The dictionary definitions below seem to contradict one another...*</sub>

> ### **implied**  <sub><sup>(ɪmˈplaɪd)  *adj*</sup></sub>
>
> **1.** hinted at or ***suggested***; not directly expressed:
>             *There was no express or implied restriction on its use.*
>
> **impliedly** *adv*
>
> <sup>Source: [Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged ©2014](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/implied)</sup>

> ### im-ply  <sub><sup>(ĭm-plī′) *tr.v.* **im-plied**, **im-ply-ing**, **im-plies**</sup></sub>
>
> **1.** **a.** To express or state indirectly: *She implied that she was in a hurry.*
>     **b.** To make evident indirectly: *His fine clothes implied that he was wealthy.*
>
> **2.** To involve by logical necessity; entail: *Life implies growth and death.*
>
> <sup>Source: [American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language ©2016](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=implied)</sup>

---

I've seen the term used in `/?` listings for `CHKDSK`, `CLEANMGR` and others...
[image: CHKDSK Screenshot]

Comment: "Implies" is used in the formal logic sense: A -> B (A implies B) means that, if A is true, then B is necessarily true. So, if `/R` is specified, then the effect of `/F` is automatically invoked without its being explicitly included in the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the DOS/Windows Command Prompt, `implies ...` means that you do not have to specify both switches; specifying the one that implies the other is sufficient. In the example you present, if you are specifying any of `/R`, `/X`, or `/B`, you need not specify `/F` as well, as `CHKDSK` will fix any errors it finds, which is what `/F` does.

Comment: Alright, thanks — that's what I hypothesized; I just wanted to make sure.  It's kinda of crucial information!

Answer (score 0):

> I thought I knew what an implication was, until looking into this.

What did you think it was?

> If the description for switch /R says (implies /F), does that mean
>   that using this switch automatically also includes /F regardless of
>   whether I add it?

yes

> Or is it just strongly suggested that I add /F?

heh, no

Comment: *That* is what I thought it meant - until I noticed that half the dictionary definitions say it's a "suggestion" so I figured it's safer to confirm since it's pretty crucial information.

Comment: @ashleedawg  technical people don't tend to use the suggestion definition.

Comment: Every rule has it's exception, and it doesn't hurt to confirm doubts by asking questions... especially in a Q&A forum.  (In fact, it *benefits*  both the Q'ers *and* the A'ers, in multiple ways.)  Now I'll never wonder about that again, *and* didn't have to risk an assumption, *and* "one day" someone else will be wondering the same thing and this post will solve their question too - with even less effort than it did for me.  Thanks again! :)

Comment: @ashleedawg  I think you asked a reasonable question. Also, I'm not aware of any exception to  what you refer to as "the rule".

Comment: @ashleedawg and even if you did look at it as a suggestion, you could then question whether that means A)A suggestion that it already does blah or B)A suggestion that you should do blah(like a recommended usage). But it's not a suggestion so it's not A or B, and it's certainly not 'B'.    It's a statement of certainty that it already does blah and that therefore you don't need to be explicit in telling it to do blah.